# How can I move the ByteRange from the front to the end of a PDF file using IExternalSignatureContainer in iTextPdf?

Tags: java, pdf

I implemented interface com.itextpdf.signatures.IExternalSignatureContainer to sign a pdf file using Java,I found that the ByteRange was always placed at the front of the pdf file,but I want to place the ByteRange to the end of the pdf file,could anyone tell me how to do this.

I tried to modify the method void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic),but it hasn't any effect

Comment: If you sign in append mode, the **ByteRange** entry will be part of the new incremental update which is appended at the end of the file. But out of interest, what difference does it make for you where that array is located?

Comment: If there are 2 more than signs in a pdf file,those ByteRanges were all placed at the front of the pdf file, so it's difficult to determine the data range of each ByteRange

Comment: If you apply a second signature to a PDF, you **must** use append mode at least for the second signing unless invalidating the first signature is not an issue for you. Other than that, though, it is clear which byte ranges are related to which signature, simply follow the object references from the signature field dictionaries.